# ‘I tickled his foot excitedly’

Tags: adverbs

Can ‘I tickled his foot excitedly’ mean I tickled his foot so I made him excited? I want to use ‘interestedly’ instead of ‘interestingly.’

Comment: Adverbs beg the question: "How did I tickle his foot?

Comment: ***interestedly*** is barely "English", so you should probably forget that one. In your context, the two possible adverbial forms are 1) ***excitedly*** (the ***tickler*** was excited), and 2) ***excitingly*** (the ***person being tickled*** became excited).

Comment: Compare *He watched her **irritatedly*** (***he*** was irritated while he watched her), and *He watched her **irritatingly*** (***she*** was irritated by him watching her).

Comment: It seems to me that with OP's ***excitedly / excitingly*** and my own ***irritatedly / irritatingly***, both the adverbial forms definitely modify the relevant verb (***tickled*** or ***watched***). The difference is in ***how*** they modify it (in the past participle-based forms, it's the ***agent / subject*** who's excited / irritated, whereas with the *continuous* participle-based forms, it's the ***patient / object*** who experiences those emotions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't.

The adverb "excitedly" modifies the verb "tickled." Since the subject "I" is who is performing the action, it describes the manner in which the subject "I" performs the action. It certainly doesn't describe the manner in which the owner of the foot responded since the owner of the foot isn't even in the sentence at all, the direct object of the verb being "his foot," not *him*.

To be clear, if the adverb were to modify how the direct object of the verb responded to the verb's action, it would be the direct object "his foot" being excited, not this *him* (the owner of "his foot") you refer to in your question but who doesn't actually appear in the sentence itself, just "his foot."

Comment: Then, is ‘excitingly’ proper?

Comment: @Benjamin your last part of the answer is not clear. And in the second paragraph, you mentioned that the owner of the foot is not at all mentioned, I think when the sentence says "his foot", I think the mention is explicitly made. Anyway that is questionable and doubtful, so let's not get there. But please clarify your last paragraph. My point is you said "excitedly" modifies "his foot" (which i believe is wrong) in the last paragraph, but in the previous paragraph you said it modifies "I".

Comment: "I tickled him excitedly" does it mean the direct object is responding to "tickling" excitedly?

Comment: @Man_From_India - Well, if it's not clear to you, I'm glad you asked . No, I didn't say in the second paragraph that the adverb "excitedly" modifies "his foot." What I said was "if the adverb ***were to*** modify ***how*** the direct object of the verb responded to the verb's action." I was speaking hypothetically for the sake of discussion to clarify that even if the adverb "excitedly" did, which, again, it doesn't, it would only modify *how* the direct object "his foot" responded, ***not*** modify the direct object "his foot" and ***definitely not*** modify the nonexistent object "him."

Comment: @Man_From_India - I do appreciate how you may *think* it saying "his foot" is the foot's owner appearing in the sentence. While it's a mistake to think so, it's an ***extremely*** common mistake, one that leads to extremely common grammatical errors, like dangling participles. Now, were "his foot" a synecdoche there, you'd have a leg to stand on, as it were, but it's clearly not. I am *truly* glad you brought this up, though, since it's such a common mistake to infer that an object modified by a possessive pronoun insinuates that possessive pronoun's antecedent as being the object instead. 

Comment: @Benjamin you said it could modify how the direct object of verb - "his foot" - would respond. What actually does that mean? Does that mean "excitedly" modifies "his response" in "she tickled him excitedly"?

Comment: @Man_From_India - I didn't say "it could." Again, what I said was, "if the adverb *were to*." That doesn't mean "it could."

Comment: @Benjamin could you please explain a bit more what you meant (about the hypothetical situation you mentioned) citing some example sentences?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124363/discussion-between-man-from-india-and-benjamin-harman).

Answer (score 0):

"Excitedly" is an adverb, modifying *tickled*. Tickling might be done quickly or slowly, roughly or gently, but not *excitedly*. *Excitedly* is how one behaves, not how one makes someone *else* behave. E.G., "I waited excitedly for his return."

As for ‘interestedly’ instead of ‘interestingly,’ **where would you use them?** Both are valid adverbs, but certainly not for toe tickling.

Comment: I just made a sentence to use ‘-edly.’